# Create Oracle scheme from PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a Oracle scheme into SQL file. I'm interested is it possible to run the SQL file from PL/SQL block and import the scheme into Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

That architecture doesn't generally make a lot of sense...

You could, assuming the .SQL file is stored on the database server, write a PL/SQL block that uses `UTL_FILE` to read the file, identify the delimiters, and then use dynamic SQL to execute each individual statement.  But that would be a pretty hefty amount of work to get right.

Again, assuming the .SQL file is stored on the database server, you could also write a Java stored procedure that called out to the host operating system, launched SQL*Plus, connected back to the database, and executed the .SQL file.  That would be less work than trying to parse the contents of the file yourself.  But it would involve a second session and a separate executable which adds a bunch of complexity as well.

Is there a reason that you don't simply fire up SQL*Plus, pass it the .SQL file, and let SQL*Plus run?  What does PL/SQL add in this situation?

Comment: What about this idea: I tested to create Java program that reads .sql file with Oracle scheme. But I have a problem with the comments into the sql file. Is it possible to create Java program which starts PL/SQL block from the Java code, then the PL/SQL block reads the sql file and creates Oracle scheme. The main purpose is to create Java standalone application which installs Oracle scheme by network or deployed on the Oracle server. Any idea what is the best solution?

Comment: @user1908169 - PL/SQL runs on the database server so it only has access to resources that the database has.  If you're talking about a Java application running an installer, that application is, presumably, running somewhere other than the database server.  So it wouldn't make sense to try to use PL/SQL.  If this is a product you are building, it would seem more reasonable to provide it with a different input file that stores the statements you want to run in a format that is easier to parse (say, an XML file).

Comment: @user1908169 - From a security standpoint, however, Oracle DBAs are going to be far more willing to take a .SQL file that you provide and execute that rather than granting whatever Oracle database account they have to set up for your application to connect with the privileges to create a bunch of objects (doubly so if you really mean creating a schema which would mean creating a user).

Comment: XML file is not an option because I usually use Toad Database modeler to generate scheme. Do you know Open source tool which can import scheme into Oracle?

Comment: @user1908169 - SQL*Plus and/or SQL Developer can both run a .SQL file.  Both are freely available from Oracle though neither is open source.